# Do I need a comma before the following italicized text?

Tags: punctuation

> The letter didn’t start with her customary(,) *Hi, I’m Aiko Kobayashi, the girl
>   who …* In fact, it only had two lines.

Do I need that comma? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you choose to use italics instead of quotation marks to set off a direct quotation, you're already somewhat outside the "rules" and can do whatever you feel best illustrates your personal narrative.  See this question on ELU:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/use-quotation-marks-or-italics-for-written-quotes

However, it can help the reader understand the sentence better if you mark off the direct quote with commas, as you would any other quotation:

> *Hi,* she said with a smile, *do you come here often?*
>
> *221A Baker Street,* he muttered to the woman next to him. *Why do I feel like I know that address?*

In novels it's common practice to italicize *internal* dialogue -- a character's thoughts or feelings, or (sometimes) telepathic communication:

> *Stop reading my mind!* she thought furiously
>   *I'm sorry, I sometimes can't help it,* he thought back.
>
> *I wonder what Gordon Ramsey would have for dinner tonight?* she mused to herself as she wandered through the market.

So, using italics for direct quotes can be confusing as it's not clear whether the quote is *internal* or *out loud*.  It's still fine, but you should use the same punctuation consistently so the reader can get used to it.

Comment: Bear in mind that this ISN'T a direct quote of speech, so perhaps italics are suitable. I think I wouldn't bat an eyelid at seeing italics to denote quotations from letters in a novel.

Answer (score 3):

Proceed as if the quotation marks were there. It is a direct quotation, so you do need a comma. See rule 3a [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp).

> The letter didn't start with her customary, *Hi, I'm Aiko Kobayashi, the girl who…* In fact, it only had two lines.

Comment: The phrasing "her customary" **clearly** indicates the secondary definition of _customary_: "according to a person's habitual practice."